# sql indexes insert only one record from duplication in bulk insertion

Tags: sql, indexing

i have an index with 4 column, i need to insert bulk of rows from select query having duplicated rows, i need to make this key index to prevent inserting the second duplicated row ,just insert one of them
how can i do it ?

Comment: Have a unique constraint, unique index, or a primary key.

Comment: @jarlh i have make ID a primary key but still not working

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

More than an index, what you want is a **database constraint**.

For example, if your table has four columns as in:

```
create table my_table (
  col1 int not null,
  col2 int not null,
  col3 int not null,
  col4 int not null,
  constraint unique_row unique (col1, col2, col3, col4)
);
```

The included constraint prevents any duplicate row, since it includes **all table columns**.

As a side effect, the database will create a unique index to *implement* this constraint. But the key aspect is the constraint.

**Note**: The example in PostgreSQL (you didn't specify any database) but should work on most databases.

Comment: same response `Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UC_ATT'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EmployeeAtt'.`

Comment: i need to make the query ignore the duplication and insert one value

Comment: Then, you can implement a **pre-insert** trigger. With it, you can check the value exists and ignore it.